# PivotTable Fields too Big

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an excel file in which PivotTable Fields view is too big (screen shot below). I tried the following but nothing seems to work

1. Change the Zoom in the Bottom right screen
2. Create a new pivot in that file

This issue is there only with this particular file. Newer files seems okay. There is a lot of work done on this file, and it will be hard to copy it over to a new one. Is there a fix to reduce the size of the PivotTable Fields view?

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: in the DisplaySettings at the  bottom, there are two more options to the right of the highlighted one and before the Zoom slider.  Any changes when you select one of these?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and it was because I am using my laptop as a second monitor- I dragged and viewed the excel file to my laptop screen and then dragged it back to my main screen and the field list went back to the normal size.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked "Display Settings" at the bottom of excel under the PivotTable Fields.  Then I selected "Optimze for compatibility (application restart required).   AFter restarting excel, the fields window was back to normal